# Monitor does not "wakup" after suspend

Tags: suspend, monitor

I have [Dell UltraSharp 49 Curved Monitor - U4919DW](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-ultrasharp-49-curved-monitor-u4919dw/apd/210-arnw/monitors-monitor-accessories) and the monitor stays in standby after suspend mode is exited. Sometimes it wakes up after a while. Any clues how to debug this?

- Ubuntu version: 20.04
- Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K
- Graphics card: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (integrated)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to check the settings of the monitor. Problem like these can be caused by **suspended mode** is `active` or **Sleep mode**.

Check your monitor settings from the monitor itself before going into the computer settings. Because this situation has happened to me before.

Comment: You were absolutely right, I found this setting at "Personalize -> Monitor Sleep". Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm very happy to hear that your problem has been solved! Glad to hear that :)